# Help determining whether this is zero-knowledge and of which type (perfect/ computational)

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> The following is an interactive proof for knowledge of the factorization of $n=pq$ ($p,q$ are two large primes), where $P$ doesn't wish to reveal the factorization itself ($p,q$). Determine whether it is a ZK proof. If it is, prove whether it is
> perfect zero-knowledge or computational zero knowledge.
>
> - V chooses a random $r \in_R \mathbb{Z}^*_n$, computes $x = r^2 \mod n$ and sends it to $P$.
> - P chooses a random $y \in_R \mathbb{Z}^*_n$, computes $z=xy^{-1} \mod n$, and sends $y,z$ back to $V$.
> - $V$ asserts that $x=yz$, and asks P for the square root of $y$ or the square root of $z$.
> - P sends the square root back to V.
> - V verifies the response.

First, I cannot see why there is always a root for either $y$ or $z$, because since $y$ is chosen randomly, it could by a random QNR, meaning also $z$ is. **What am I missing here?**

That aside, if there is indeed a QR for $z$ or $y$, I thought of the following simulator:

- Get $x=r^2 \mod n$ from $V^*$.
- Guess whether $V^*$ will ask for $z$ or $y$.
- Prepare a random $s$ and set either $s^2=:y \mod n$ or $s^2=:z \mod n$ accordingly, and compute the other value, namely $z$ or $y$.
- Send $y, z$ to $V^*$. Get $V^*$'s root-request.
- If the request matches the guess, send $s$. Otherwise start afresh.
- Output $(n, r, y, z, s)$

Since $s$ is randomly distributed, then $y,z$ are also randomly distributed, and the output matches $V^*$'s view ($r$ is, too, randomly distributed).

**Is this simulator correct?** (I'm very new to this, so would also appreciated any general advice on how to approach these).

**How does one tell whether this is perfect-zk or computational?** I really don't have any strong intuition here either way. How to approach such questions?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This seems like homework, so don't expect direct answers

Comment: Regarding your second question, perfect or computational zero knowledge depends on where the real view vs. the simulated view of an adversary are either computationally or perfectly indistinguishable (referring to their corresponding distributions).

Comment: This is not homework (it's September...). I'm preparing for an exam using old exams. Also, I believe I've solved it for the most part with what I've written. I don't see how one can learn without correcting mistakes and learning from others with more experience.

Comment: I understand the definition of computation vs perfectly indistinguishable distributions. I just don't know how to determine that here formally. To me, intuitively, it seems identical to the view since all elements in the distribution are randomly distributed the same way.

Comment: I cannot understand what is the purpose of this interactive proof.

Comment: The purpose is for $P$ to prove that they know the factorization of $N=pq$ (sorry - it's part of a multi-part question, so I wrote only the portion I'm stuck on. Will clarify in the main text).

Comment: Okay, you can update your answer providing all the details. Also with a quick look, I don't see any zero knowledge property here. Whatever P computes, V can also compute. Also referring to your update p and q aren't mentioned anywhere :/

Comment: Hopefully, I've now added all the relevant information in the first line.

Comment: Furthermore you have to provide more information on what is shared before the proof. All the proofs for zk are made in the crs model. Do we know any properties of $\mathbb{Z}_n^{*}$, ring or group (I can guess it is a group), commutative or not?

Comment: Unfortunately your question still lacks information about $N$, $p$, $q$. You can check it again if it makes sense and I will come back later.

Comment: The [current problem statement](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/101889/3) uses $N$ and $n$, I'll assume for the same thing. It also omits stating that $p$ and $q$ are distinct, secret, and randomly chosen, and that $n$ is public, which I'll assume too. The problem statement remains bogus because $y$ could be a QNR, as noted.

Comment: First - thanks to both of you :) I double checked - nothing else is mentioned in the question regarding $p,q$, nor regarding $Z^*_n$.  $N$ is indeed $n$ (typo on my part - will now fix). I guess it is flawed. Second - If any of you could explain (or point to a good resource on the matter), how to approach "perfect" vs "computational" in the context of ZK proofs, that would be very helpful.

Comment: You could solve the QNR issue by doing this at step 2: P choose a random $a$ and sets $y = a^2$, then proceed. I think the simulator is perfectly indistinguishable from the real protocol execution. How could a distinguisher tell the difference between the real and simulated views?